# telnetting my socket listening port is closing socket

Tags: c, sockets, telnet, forceclose

I am new to this website so I do appologize in advance if this question has been answered before though I have searched it before opening it to everyone here.

I am using socket programming in one of my C program. It has server and client modules where sever and client can communicate in both directions. Program is working fine as I am able to send files and messages in both directions. 
My server program is using port `3873` and I have confirmed this with `netstat -anp | grep 3873`

I have observed one weird behaviour with socket especially when I try to connect socket using browser such as `http://localhost:3873` or `telnet localhost 3873`. It immediately closed socket and subsequent 'netstat -anp | grep 3873' output confirms that localhost is no longer listening on the port `3873`.

I would really appreciate if someone can shed light on this behavior. Is it expected behavior?

Here is relevant section from the server code: Main program initiate a dedicated thread and calls startFileServerMT, which subsequent calls handleClient to service each client connected to server on the socket

```
int handleClient(void *ptr){
    DEBUG("Inside the %s %s() \n",__FILE__,__func__);
    int  connectSOCKET;
    connectSOCKET = (int ) ptr;
    char recvBUFF[4096],sendBUFF[4096];
    char *filename;
    FILE * recvFILE;
    char *header[4096];    
    while(1){
        if( recv(connectSOCKET, recvBUFF, sizeof(recvBUFF), 0) > 0){
            if(!strncmp(recvBUFF,"FBEGIN",6)) {                          
                recvBUFF[strlen(recvBUFF) - 2] = 0;
                parseArgs(header,recvBUFF);                                 
                filename = (char*) strngDup(header[1]);                                
                DEBUG("  About to receive file: %s\n", filename);
            }

            char *rfile = ALLOC(sizeof(char) * (strlen(This.uploadDIR) + strlen(filename) + 35));
            strcpy(rfile,This.uploadDIR);

            if (strngLastChar(rfile) == '/'){
                strcat(rfile,filename);
            }else{
                strcat(rfile,"/");
                strcat(rfile,filename);        
            }
            DEBUG("  Absolute file is : %s\n", rfile);
            recvBUFF[0] = 0;
            if ((recvFILE = fopen (rfile,"w" )) == NULL){
                LogError("Server could not create file %s on the shared location %s.\n",filename,This.uploadDIR);                
            }else{
                bzero(recvBUFF,4096);
                int fr_block_sz, write_sz;
                while((fr_block_sz = recv(connectSOCKET, recvBUFF, 512, 0)) > 0 ){
                    write_sz = fwrite (recvBUFF , sizeof(recvBUFF[0]) , fr_block_sz , recvFILE );
                    DEBUG("  Received buffer is : %s\n", recvBUFF);
                    if(write_sz < fr_block_sz){
                        LogError("Failed writing file %s on the Server shared location.\n",filename);
                        break;
                    }
                    bzero(recvBUFF,4096);
                    recvBUFF[0] = 0;
                    if(write_sz == 0 || fr_block_sz != 512 ){   
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if(fr_block_sz < 0){
                    if(errno == EAGAIN){
                        LogError("Server collection file %s receive timed out.\n",filename);
                    }else{
                        LogError("Failed file %s transfer due to error %d\n",filename,errno);
                        fclose(recvFILE);
                        FREE(rfile);
                        // Start - Following code send failed status to client    
                        sprintf(sendBUFF,"FSTATUS:FAILED\r\n");    

                        if (send(connectSOCKET, sendBUFF, sizeof(sendBUFF), 0) >= 0){
                            DEBUG("File transfer status for file %s sent\n",filename);
                        }else{
                            DEBUG("Failed sending transfer status for file %s\n",filename);
                            return FALSE;
                        } 

                        // End

                        close(connectSOCKET);
                        return FALSE;
                    }
                }
                    DEBUG("File %s received on OM Server successfully.\n",filename);

                    // Start - Following code send failed status to client    
                    sprintf(sendBUFF,"FSTATUS:SUCCESS\r\n");    

                    if (send(connectSOCKET, sendBUFF, sizeof(sendBUFF), 0) >= 0){
                        DEBUG("File transfer status for file %s sent\n",filename);
                    }else{
                        DEBUG("Failed sending transfer status for file %s\n",filename);
                        return FALSE;
                    } 
                    // End

                    fclose(recvFILE);
                    updateTargets(rfile);
                    FREE(rfile);
                    close(connectSOCKET);
                    break;

            }
        }
        else {
            LogInfo("Client dropped connection\n");
        }

/** End*/  
        return TRUE;
    }    
}

int startFileServerMT(){
    DEBUG("Inside %s %s() \n",__FILE__,__func__);

    int listenSOCKET, connectSOCKET[512],thread_status;
    int socketINDEX = 0;

    pthread_t clientFileThread[512];
    socklen_t clientADDRESSLENGTH[512];
    struct sockaddr_in clientADDRESS[512], serverADDRESS;    


    if((listenSOCKET = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0 ){
        LogAbortError("File server could not create socket.\n");
        close(listenSOCKET);
        return FALSE;        
    }

    serverADDRESS.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverADDRESS.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);  
    serverADDRESS.sin_port = htons(This.serverport);

    if (bind(listenSOCKET, (struct sockaddr *) &serverADDRESS, sizeof(serverADDRESS)) < 0) {
        LogAbortError("File server could not bind socket and will stop server now.\n");
        close(listenSOCKET);
        This.stopped = TRUE;
        return FALSE;
    }

    if(listen(listenSOCKET, 5) == -1){
        LogAbortError("Server failed to listen on port %d and will stop server now.\n",This.serverport);
        close(listenSOCKET);
        This.stopped = TRUE;
        return FALSE;        
    }else{
        LogInfo("Server listening on port %d successfully.\n",This.serverport);        
    }

    clientADDRESSLENGTH[socketINDEX] = sizeof(clientADDRESS[socketINDEX]);

    while(TRUE){   
       // DEBUG("  Inside the file server main loop index[%d].\n",socketINDEX);

        connectSOCKET[socketINDEX] = accept(listenSOCKET, (struct sockaddr *) &clientADDRESS[socketINDEX], &clientADDRESSLENGTH[socketINDEX]);
            if(connectSOCKET[socketINDEX] < 0){
            LogError("Server could not accept connection.\n");
            close(listenSOCKET);
            return FALSE;
        }else
            DEBUG("  Another client connected to server socket.\n");

        ThreadCreateDetached( &clientFileThread[socketINDEX], handleClient, connectSOCKET[socketINDEX]);     

        if(socketINDEX=512) {
            socketINDEX = 0;
        } else { 
            socketINDEX++;
        }                                  

        if (This.stopped == TRUE){
            close(listenSOCKET);
            return TRUE;
        }      
/** End*/  
//        return TRUE;
    }

    close(listenSOCKET);
    return TRUE;

}
```

Comment: It sounds like your server program is crashing. Have you checked what happens with the server?

Comment: He wants us to debug his server code without publishing his source code.... Joachim already made good guess ;-)

Comment: Check this fast networking in C tutorial I uploaded some time ago for a similar question. http://www.scribd.com/doc/120274805/QGNP
Hope this helps :)

Comment: The HTTP and telnet protocols send data over the connection that your code is probably not supporting. You need to proof your code against such unrecognized data (eg. by discarding it, and logging an error).

Comment: The problem is most likely in your code. Show us some server code or we can't help you.

Comment: Here is relevant code section from server

Comment: `recvBUFF[strlen(recvBUFF) - 2] = 0;` makes me shiver. I know the code is loaded with memset/bzero of the buffers before use, but this is not the way to go IMnsvHO. Please **use the return value** you get from read() write() recv() send().

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem - or at least a part of your problem. It's not only an off-by-one error (connectSOCKET accepts indices from 0-511 *inclusive* so if you're at 512, you've already written past the end of the connectSOCKET array) but you do an assignment instead of a comparison:

```
    if(socketINDEX=512) { // Error: you are *setting* socketINDEX to 512, 
                          // then immediately *resetting* it back to 0. So
                          // every new connection overrides the existing
                          // socket.
        socketINDEX = 0;
    } else { 
        socketINDEX++;
    }
```

As a sidenote, you really ought to refactor your code and try to clean it up.

Comment: Thanks for your observations Nik, I have corrected this and collected more information about server crash and found that one invalid pointer was crashing the server, which I have corrected now.

Comment: if recvBUFF is nto FBEGIN then filename is not initialised and failing memory allocation for  *rfile.      `            if(!strncmp(recvBUFF,"FBEGIN",6)) {                          
                recvBUFF[strlen(recvBUFF) - 2] = 0;
                parseArgs(header,recvBUFF);                                 
                filename = (char*) strngDup(header[1]);                                
                DEBUG("  About to receive file: %s\n", filename);
            }
            
            char *rfile = ALLOC(sizeof(char) * (strlen(This.uploadDIR) + strlen(filename) + 35));`